# Making a managed object truly deletable

Tags: c#, idisposable, weak-references

**Background:**

I tried asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048573/deleting-objects-which-are-being-referenced-in-many-places) question yesturday but with no real conclusion, so I thought I would try asking it in a different way as this problem is causing me a big headache.

My application is an embedded HMI design tool. This allows the user (who are internal developers) to visually design how the embedded HMI will look and then, with a button click, generates the C code. Most of this now works.

One of the main things the tool does is allows the user to create new screens (which can then have controls dropped on them). In my application a 'screen' is an object. When a new screen is added it is placed in a `List<Screen>` which is later used to generate the C code.

One of the properties of that screen is the `private Screen nextScreen` which is a reference to another screen object which indicates what screen to show next when the navigation button is pressed. Again all this works great.

**Problem:**

However, when playing with the tool to generate code we found a problem. 2 screens were created, with the first screen having its `nextScreen` property set to the 2nd. A bit later it was decided that the 2nd screen was wrong so it was deleted and a new screen created. However they forgot to set the first screen `nextScreen` property to this new screen, so it was still referencing the original screen which, visually had been deleted.

When the code was generated the resulting C code failed to compile as the first screen was referencing a screen which, within the generated C environment, did not exist.

**Question:**

So my question is how can I best implement a way of deletion which ensures that anything that references an object being 'deleted' knows about it and sets that property to null?

**Thoughts so far:**

1) I have tried creating the 'nextScreen' property as a WeakReference which does work but it means I have to manually call the GC.Collect() every time a delete is done... not ideal from my understanding! (My example of trying this can be found in the link at the top of this post)

2) I could, upon deletion, check all objects for a reference to the one being deleted and set it to null. However what I have described above is just one of the many objects which make up the HMI, most of which have one or more references to other objects. So this could be slow and in my mind just doesnt seem right.

3) Maybe use IDisposable??? but from my understanding this is for unmanaged code!

Any ideas or areas for me to read up on would be great as I'm now pulling my hair out over this... not that I have much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ObjectPool pattern to create and delete object and some Wrapper on it's objects, to control their livetime

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion which I have looked into, however this does not really provide the functionality I require as described above. I have continued to investigate and have come to the conclusion that there isnt really anything for my purpose, which really supprises me. I am, therefore, currently implementing my own manager class and supporting interface which I shall post once complete.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental design imperatives of the GC is if there is any means by which code might encounter a reference to an object, the object will continue to exist.  There is no way to "delete" an object such that references to it will become invalid.  There are, however, two things you can do:

1. Have your class include a field which indicates whether it has been invalidated, and have code which receives or follows a reference to a class instance, check that field to ensure the instance is still valid.  If code sets that field within an instance, any references to it will no longer be references to a valid instance, but will (by definition) become references to an invalidated instance.
2. If you create a `WeakReference` to an object, the `Target` property of that `WeakReference` will become `null` when the GC detects that no non-weak references to the target exist (if a reference to a non-null target is copied to another variable, that variable will keep the target alive even if the weak reference had been the only thing in the universe with a reference to the target).  Forcing a full garbage-collection cycle will generally invalidate immediately any weak references to objects which aren't strongly referenced anywhere, but would represent something of an abuse of the GC system.
3. Implement a "find all used objects" routine which counts how many times it has been run, and have a field within each class instance into which that routine will store its counter.  Any object which should be considered "used" will hold the value the "find all used objects" routine counter held the last time it was run.  This is somewhat like what the GC does with objects it knows about, but if you do this yourself you can decide what forms of reference should justify regarding an object as "used".

Comment: can you expand on your 3rd point a bit more. It sounds interesting but I dont completely follow how it would work. thanks.

Comment: Conceptually, think of each object as having a "last accessed" field, and having a process which "accesses" everything it can find in some fashion, updating the field appropriately in every object it encounters.  If an object hasn't been accessed since the last time one started a scan that has since been completed, that would imply that it is not possible for a scan performed in that fashion to find the object.  Using actual "wall-clock" time for the last access, however, would either require storing enough mostly-useless precision to distinguish between objects whose last access...

Comment: ...predated the start of the scan versus those whose last access occurred during the scan.  Replacing the clock with a counter that is incremented at the start of each scan avoids that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new generic class called `Deletable<T>` to wrap your objects.  It would work similar to `Nullable<T>` in that it contains a property of type `T` that holds the original value.  It would need a readonly `bool` property `IsDeleted` that indicates if the wrapped value has been deleted, and a `Delete` method that NULLs out the wrapped value, and sets the `IsDeleted` flag.

Everything that uses `Screen` objects would switch to `Deletable<Screen>`. When a screen gets deleted, call `Delete` on the wrapper.  Any code that cares if a screen is deleted can just check `scr.IsDeleted` before using `scr.Value`.

This will allow garbage collection to clean up any large objects, while leaving a nice small "flag" value in its place that you can use to check to see if the real object has been deleted.

Comment: thanks for the input. interesting idea... i also did not know about Nullable<T>. Using use suggestion though, you say that it would allow the garbage collector to clean up, but is that true? As i guess the Deletable<T> object will still hold a reference to the actual objetc so would not get collected??

Comment: Other objects would only hold a reference to the wrapper. The only reference to the real object is in the wrapper. When you call Delete on the wrapper it would null out the only reference, making it available for garbage collection.